# Using Feign in a standalone library vs a Springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-feign

I want to create a client for Some-Micro-Service as a library (Some-Micro-Service-Client) that way it can easily be included in the pom of Some-Other-Micro-Service.

I would like to use Feign because it makes things easier, but I am not sure if this is possible with my architecture. All of the Feign examples that I see start with using the @EnableFeignClient annotation on the SpringBootAppplication class, but since I don't want the client library to have to be "started up" I want to know if it is possible just to include it in the library without using the EnableFeignClient annotation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [feign](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.openfeign) without `@EnableFeingClient` annotation. Assume, we want to receive data from [this](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) API. In below example I used [Feign Core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.openfeign/feign-core) and [Feign Gson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.openfeign/feign-gson) dependencies.

First of all we need to create class, in which we will get the json result:

```
public class TODO {
    private long id;
    private long userId;
    private String title;
    private boolean completed;

    \\ getters and setters ...
}
```

After that we declare the interface with the future rest-client methods:

```
public interface TaskApi {

    @RequestLine("GET /todos/{id}")
    TODO getTODO(@Param("id") int id);
}
```

And in conclusion let's build desired rest client and make test request:

```
public class FeignTest {

    private static final String API_PATH = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TaskApi taskApi = Feign.builder()
                .decoder(new GsonDecoder())
                .target(TaskApi.class, API_PATH);
        TODO todo = taskApi.getTODO(1);
    }
}
```

For more information and possibilities you can read in [official repository](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign).

Comment: This was really helpful, but as I'm unit testing FeignTest class, i am unable to mock the TaskAPI normally (with @Mock on the declaration and then doReturn when taskApi.getTODO(any()). Any help on this?

Comment: FeignTest is a pretty sample class for demonstrating how to create and use feign. In practice, you can create TaskApi object in another place and put it as a constructor parameter of FeignTest class. As result, you will have the possibility to mock the TaskApi object in unit tests.