# Mocking an OpenFeign client for Unit Testing in a spring library and NOT for a spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, microservices, spring-cloud-feign, openfeign

I've implemented a feign client that calls a get API based on this [official repository](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign). I have a rule class `UserValidationRule` that needs to call that get API call `getUser()` and validate some stuff. That works as expected but when I get to testing that rule class, mocking the feign client is not successful and it continues to call the actual API. I've simplified the situation so please ignore the simplicity lol. This is a follow up question I have after i found this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56383675/using-feign-in-a-standalone-library-vs-a-springboot-application) question

The API returns this model:

```
@Data
public class userModel {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

}
```

The interface with the rest client method:

```
public interface UserServiceClient {

    @RequestLine("GET /users/{id}")
    UserModel getUser(@Param("id") int id);
}
```

And in the rule class, i build the feign client and call the API:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class UserValidationRule {

    private static final String API_PATH = "http://localhost:8080";

    private UserServiceClient userServiceClient;


    public void validate(String userId, ...) {
            // some validations 
            validateUser(userId);

    }

    private void validateUser(String userId) {
            userServiceClient = getServiceClient();
            UserModel userModel = userServiceClient.gerUser(userId);
            
            // validate the user logic
        }
    }

    private UserServiceClient getServiceClient() {
           return Feign.builder()
                  .encoder(new GsonEncoder())
                  .decoder(new GsonDecoder())
                  .target(UserServiceClient.class, API_PATH);
    }
}
```

And here comes the test class:

```
public class UserValidationRuleTest {

    private UserServiceClient userServiceClient = mock(UserServiceClient.class);
    private UserValidationRule validationRule = new UserValidationRule();
    private UserModel userModel;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        userModel = generateUserModel();
    }


    @Test
    public void validateWhenAgeIsNotBlank() {

        doReturn(userModel).when(userServiceClient).getUser(any());
        validationRule.validate("123", ...);
        // some logic ...
        assertEquals(.....);
        verify(userServiceClient).getUser(any());
    }



    private UserModel generateUserModel() {
        UserModel userModel = new UserModel();
        userModel.setName("Cody");
        userModel.setAge("22");
        return accountModel;
    }
}
```

As I debug `validateWhenAgeIsNotBlank()`, i see that the userModel is not the one that's generated in the test class and the values are all null. If I pass in an actual `userId`, i get an actual UserModel that I have in my db.

I think the problem is that `UserServiceClient` is not being mocked. The `verify` is failing as it says the `getUser()` is not invoked. It might be something to do with how the feign client is declared in the `UserValidationRule` with the feign.builder()...
Please correct me if I'm wrong and tell me what I'm missing or any suggestions on how to mock it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using the spring managed `UserServiceClient` bean. Every time you call `UserValidationRule.validate` it calls `validateUser` which in turn calls the `getServiceClient` method. This `getServiceClient` creates a new instance of `UserServiceClient` for each invocation. This means when testing the mocked `UserServiceClient` is not in use at all.

I would restructure the code as below;

First either declare `UserServiceClient` as final with `@RequiredArgsConstructor` or replace `@RequiredArgsConstructor` with `@AllArgsConstructor`. The purpose of this change is to allow an instance of `UserServiceClient` be injected rather than creating internally in the service method.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserValidationRule {

    private final UserServiceClient userServiceClient;

.... // service methods

}
```

Then have a separate `Configuration` class that builds the feign client as spring bean;

```
@Bean
private UserServiceClient userServiceClient() {
       return Feign.builder()
              .encoder(new GsonEncoder())
              .decoder(new GsonDecoder())
              .target(UserServiceClient.class, API_PATH);
}
```

At runtime this bean will now be injected into the `UserValidationRule`.

As for the unit test changes you are creating the mock correctly but aren't setting/injecting that mock anywhere. You either need to use `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` annotations or manually create instance of `UserValidationRule` in your `@Before` method.

Here is how `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` use should look like;

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UserValidationRuleTest {

    @Mock private UserServiceClient userServiceClient;
    @InjectMocks private UserValidationRule validationRule;
    ... rest of the code
```

or continue using `mock(...)` method and manually create `UserValidationRule`.

```
public class UserValidationRuleTest {

    private UserServiceClient userServiceClient = mock(UserServiceClient.class);
    private UserValidationRule validationRule;
    private UserModel userModel;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        validationRule = new UserValidationRule(userServiceClient);
        userModel = generateUserModel();
    }
    ... rest of the code
```

This will now ensure you are using single instance of spring managed feign client bean at runtime and mocked instance for the testing.